# Question involving basic alegbra

Tags: functions

I feel like I'm going crazy, but here's the question:
$f(x)=\frac{-2}{3}x^\frac{-4}{3}$, why is $f(-5)$ negative? Can someome show step by step. I'm most confused about the $x^\frac{-2}{3}$. When I plug in $f(-5)$, I thought I get a positive number. Please help.

Comment: $x^{-4/3} $ is positive.  -2/3 is negative.  A negative times a positive is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f (x) =-\frac 23 x^{-\frac 43}=-\frac 23 \frac 1 {x^{4/3}}=-\frac 23 \sqrt [3]{1/x^4} $.

As $1/x^4 $ is always positive.  $f $ is always negative.  Not just for $x = -5$ but **all** $x $.  (Except $x= 0$ where the function isn't defined.)

Answer (score 3):

$$(-5)^{-\frac43}=\left[(-5)^{-4}\right]^{1/3}=\frac1{625^{1/3}}=\frac1{\underbrace{5\sqrt[3]5}_{=5^{4/3}}}>0$$

Or also

$$(-5)^{-\frac43}=\left[(-5)^{1/3}\right]^{-4}=\frac1{(\sqrt[3]{-5})^4}=\frac1{(\sqrt[3]{-5})^3(\sqrt[3]{-5})}=\frac1{(-5)\cdot(-5^{1/3})}=\frac1{5^{4/3}}>0$$

Comment: So then why when I graph $f(x)$, all the y-values are negative?

Comment: When plugging in I also got a positive, but on the graph all the values are negative?

Comment: Hm? Shouldn't there be a -2/3 in there?

Comment: -2/3 is negative.  A negative times something that is always positive will be always negative.

Comment: The answer shows that **the expression that gave problems to the OP** is always positive, **and thus** $\;f(x)\;$ is always negative as the above expression is multiplied by the obviously negative factor $\;-\frac23\;$ .It is a matter of just reading *and interpretating* carefully.